# Magento Server Response Time Very High - Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor

Tags: magento2, php

Our Mangeto 2 site is loading very slowly. Server response time is 2-4s.

We started using new relic to debug the issue.

We found the following loading very slowly .

**Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::run**

**Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor::launch**

**Custom/Magento\Framework\App\Http::launch**

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: New Relic Screenshot]

Thanks,

Jack

We tried looking at our hardware but it is nowhere near maxing out. So we think it is code related

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you still need assistance, please post additional information requested on May 5, 2023 for SPEED IMPROVEMENT suggestions for your MySQL configuation - my.cnf or my.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Those are wrapper functions and you need to dig deeper. I myself prefer tideways over new relic, it gives more info and they have about 2 weeks free.

As always, 3rd-party extension audit helps. Try to disable custom plugins one by one and see which one slows the site down. From my experience, it's usually a poorly coded module that's the problem.

If interested, see my other [30 tips to speed up Magento 2](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento-2).